# How to disable a UIButton and send a UIAlertView message

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, uialertview

I am trying to disable a menu button is the array is shows is empty.

This is my code.

```
@IBAction func likedmenubuttontouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    if Globals.likedArray.isEmpty {
        likedMenuButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "No liked quotes yet", message: "No liked quotes have been chosen, go explore!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    } else {
        likedMenuButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

And in ViewDidLoad()

```
likedMenuButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

I have managed to disable the button, but I want to send a message alerting the user why the button is disabled, otherwise, its a little confusing.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the condition is opposite

Comment: oops, I forgot to mention that I put this code likedMenuButton.userInteractionEnabled = false is viewdidload()

Comment: why you make likedMenuButton.userInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: ahh, I see what you mean by your first comment, Ill edit my question

Comment: preferred way is `likedMenuButton.enabled = false` not `userInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As by default the the user Interaction is true you need not to make it true

```
@IBAction func likedmenubuttontouched(sender: AnyObject) {


        if Globals.likedArray.isEmpty {

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "No liked quotes yet", message: "No liked quotes have been chosen, go explore!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            //segue to the other view
        }
    }
```

> Also check your **array count**, that is why your wrong condition is executing

Comment: Seems to work but I get "Fatal error: Array index out of range" when there are no quotes?

Comment: It is showing because you are accessing the object at the index which is not present in the array.Check the code if you are accesing object in the array.

Comment: I believe its because of this line in the viewdidload() of another view controller  - self.favouritesLabel.text = Globals.likedArray[currentlikedArrayIndex] as String -

Comment: yes it is .Because the array contains no object,but still you are accessing the that index..

Comment: It accesses it when I touch the button, even it there is nothing, how do I stop that?

Comment: check if Globals.likedArray is not empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104367/discussion-between-khoury-and-rohit-kp).